# What is signature for a zero dimensional array in numba

Tags: python, numpy, jit, signature, numba

`numba.jit()` allows entering a type signature but I can't figure out what the signature for a zero dimensional array is.

For example:

```py
numba.jit('void(float32, float32[:])')
```

says the function return is void and the input arguments are float32 scalar and float32 1-D array.

But what is instead of a scalar I want to pass in a 0-dimensional array. What's the type signature?  I tried the obvious `float32[]` but that didn't seem to work.

In case you are wondering how one gets a 0-D array in numpy you do it like this:

```py
a = numpy.array(2)
```

which is different than

```py
a = numpy.array([2])
```

the latter is a 1-D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it using [`numba.types.Array`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html#id1):

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

#        |---------0d int array---------|
@nb.njit(nb.types.Array(nb.int64, 0, "C")())
def func():
    return np.array(2)
```

Here I used that the returned value will be a C-contiguous `int64` array with `0` dimensions. Adjust these as needed.

---

In my experience there is rarely a use-case (see ["Benefit and Limitations of Ahead-of-Time compilation"](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html#overview)) for explicitly typed functions in numba - except for compilation times or in case one needs to avoid numba using already inferred types when it should compile a new function. So, personally, I wouldn't use these signatures.

Comment: Thanks.  I would not have guessed that.  Can I ask how you knew that?  thanks again.      As for using signatures, I like the awareness of type safety.  I find to my surprise float 64s and int 64s love to sneak into numba when you turn your back.  For example, how can I  make a loop using the range function that emits i32 instead of i64?  Sure I can cast them before calling the cuda or numba code, but that's wasted effort to allocate and deallocate and can even costs registers in Cuda.

Comment: @AlexanderHamilton "Can I ask how you knew that?" A lot of experience with numba and it's easily findable in the docs if you know what you look for. In this case I knew that one can use the `numba.types` module for signatures and from then it was just about finding the `Array` documentation.

Comment: @AlexanderHamilton "I find to my surprise float 64s and int 64s love to sneak into numba when you turn your back" I generally use numpy arrays in numba because there you can control the type easily. For example instead of `range` one could use `np.arange` with a suitable `dtype`. However if you have a specific question it would be better to ask a new question instead of discussing this in comments.